# sending time dependent signal to a handler function and understanding setitimer, getitimer correctly in c

Tags: c, timer, signals, handler, interrupt

I have succeeded to make a virtual timer which sends a signal to a handler function whenever a time cycle is done:

1)used setitimer to create the timer( cycles are of equal length).
2)used sigaction and implemented a function handler s.t sigaction sends SIGVTALRM to the handler function. 
i have done it in the following manner:

```
void handler(int sig){
//some code
}

//in main:
struct sigaction action;
action.sa_handler = &handler;
sigaction (SIGVTALRM, &action, NULL);


struct itimerval timer;
timer.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
timer.it_value.tv_usec = Gquantum;
timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
timer.it_interval.tv_usec = Gquantum;
setitimer (ITIMER_VIRTUAL, &timer, NULL);
```

my problem is that sometimes I need to send a signal before the cycle is done and reset the timer:
1)how can I know the how much time left in the current cycle? (maybe its related to getitimer)

2)lets assume that im in the middle of a time cycle (time left>0):how can I send a signal to the handler function before the time cycle ends and immediatly and start the next cycle(ignore the time left)

a help would be appreciated,
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the C99 function `raise()` to raise another signal. If you've registered a signal handler for a specified signal, then control will be passed to that function.

To know how much time is left in a timer, use `getitimer()`. It expects 2 parameters: which timer to query, and where to store it. You can look at the structures manually to find the remaining time for the specified timer.